# Clipping data to shapefile using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine

I want to clip this fire data so it only displays results in my shapefile titled 'tapajos'. How do I do this?

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS').filter(
    ee.Filter.date('2000-01-01', '2018-08-10'));
var fires = dataset.select('T21');
var firesVis = {
  min: 325.0,
  max: 400.0,
  palette: ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'],
};
Map.setCenter(-119.086, 47.295, 6);
Map.addLayer(fires, firesVis, 'Fires');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can clip every image in the collection by using:

```
// This function clips images to the ROI feature collection
var clipToCol = function(image){
  return image.clip(tapajos);
};
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS').filter(
    ee.Filter.date('2000-01-01', '2018-08-10')).map(clipToCol);
var fires = dataset.select('T21');
var firesVis = {
  min: 325.0,
  max: 400.0,
  palette: ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'],
};
Map.setCenter(-119.086, 47.295, 6);
Map.addLayer(fires, firesVis, 'Fires');
```

Answer (score 2):

When you say `Map.addLayer(fires,...)`, you're implicitly calling `mosaic()` on that collection, which returns a single image.  If that's how you're doing it, clipping a single image (a composite) to a `FeatureCollection`, then you should use [`image.clipToCollection()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagecliptocollection).  If you need to clip every image in the collection first, then map a function over the `ImageCollection` in which you call [`clipToCollection()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagecliptocollection).

Comment: How do `image.clipToCollection()` and `image.clip()` differ?

Comment: If the geometries in the collection are complex and/or a lot of them, then `clipToCollection` is more efficient.  Otherwise, the geometries will need to be extracted and merged into one giant geometry, which can be expensive.